# Endless process

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, cvxopt

```
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
c = matrix([-4., -5.])
G = matrix([[2., 1., -1., 0.], [1., 2., 0., -1.]])
h = matrix([3., 3., 0., 0.])
sol = solvers.lp(c, G, h)
print sol['x']
```

I start running this code and it doesn't finish. 
PS. Python 2.7 JupyterNotebook

Comment: Why are you under the impression that it should finish? Have you proved / solved that equation yourself?

Comment: it is the sample from official webpage

Comment: Okay, so did you run it outside of Jupyter?

Comment: yes, i did but it didnt help

Comment: Try to run more basic examples. I run the code above on Pycharm and it did finished quite fast with a solution

Comment: i tried and everything worked, but when i run cvxopt functions python freezs on 5th line (sol = solvers.lp(c, G, h))